# Convert a string of numbers into numeric without a predefined function in VB

Tags: vb.net

I was given a task to do and am stuck on one part.  I have to convert a string with just 0's and 1's into numeric and then use that binary number and convert it into decimal.  Converting binary to decimal, I can do.  But getting a string and converting to numeric without using any function such as convert or tryParse or such.  Any help would be appreciated.  In VB.

```
Private Function convertToNumeric(inputText As String)
    Dim str() As String = inputText.Split(",")
    Dim result(str.Length - 1) As Integer
    For i = 0 To str.Length - 1
        result(i) = str(i)
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Is it required that you do this in separate steps? I would combine the steps, looping through a string's characters from right to left and adding the appropriate power of 2 to the result every time I found a 1.

Comment: Post the input string as well.

Comment: Check your tags vba <> vb.net.  By the code you have provided I assume you want vb.net not vba.  vba is for MS applications like excel,word, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Function ConvertStringToNumber(ByVal inputString as String) As Integer
    Dim numb as Integer = 0
    dim powr as Integer = 0
    for i as Integer = inputString.Length -1 to 0 step -1
        if inputString(i).Equals("1") Then
            numb += Math.Pow(2,powr)
        End If
        powr += 1
    next
    return numb
End Function
```

I think that is more what you are wanting

Comment: i think the `powr` should start from 1 and after every iteration should be multiplied by 2

Comment: No it should start at 0 because anything to the power of 0 is 1. and the first one from the right should be 1

Comment: if I had started the other way `powr` would of started at `inputString.Length - 1` and would be `powr -= 1` instead

Comment: yes i know. i would give an upvote but i have reached my limit. will upvote it asap.